# PHP - cURL Multi - Memory exhausted

Tags: php, curl, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function that takes an array of URLs (images) and I use `curl_multi_getcontent` to get content of each image. It works perfect for an array with < 1000 images, but for a larger array size ( > 1000 images) I am getting memory error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18237603 bytes)

I am sure I have enough memory allocated and that something else is the problem. Can you help me, please, this is my function:

```
$mh           = curl_multi_init(); // init the curl Multi
$aCurlHandles = array(); // create an array for the individual curl handles
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) { //add the handles for each url
    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $aCurlHandles[$key] = $ch;
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
}

$active = null;
//execute the multi handle
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($active > 0);

// iterate through the handles and get content
foreach ($aCurlHandles as $key => $ch) {
    $image = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); // get the content
    //
    // do something with the image ....
    //
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}

curl_multi_close($mh); // close the curl multi handler
```

Thank you!

Comment: 134Meg is not a lot of memory for a process like this. Do you have access to `php.ini` to increase maximum memory allocation?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I have. I could add `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` at the top of the function. But I am more concert about possible drawback: what if multiple people start this script at the same time, would server 'blow' away?

Comment: The OS has  techniques for queueing things if that happens.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I increase memory limit suring only that script - what whould happen if user refres page, or navigate to the other page, it should reset memory_limit to 128M?

Comment: If you alter the memory limit using your above suggestion it will apply ONLY to that one script, it has no effect on any other script ever

Comment: Why you're trying to get all 1000+ images at once? Why not to split them in lesser portions, let say, 50 images?